# How to put rectangle mask onto rectangular-ish object

Tags: python, opencv

I want to put placeholder objects for further analysis into rectangular objects.

I found code to mark corners of rectangles, but my objects' corners are not "sharp" enough.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = np.float32(gray)

corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, 100, 0.01, 60)
corners = np.int0(corners)

for corner in corners:
    x, y = corner.ravel()
    cv2.circle(img, (x,y), 3, 255, -1)

cv2.imwrite('Corners.png', img)
```

[image]
[image]

The corners are not detected properly.

1. Is there a way to achieve this?
2. How would I put a (perfect) rectangle into the object, so that it serves as placeholder?

I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using findContours and then doing minAreaRect with the contour? this fits a rectangle (can be rotated one) that includes all the points

Answer (score 1):

1. Find all contours.
2. For each contour find a bounding rotated rectangle:

   rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)

   box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect)
3. Decrease width and height of the rotated rectangle until (sum of pixels into rect == width * height)

Comment: How would I reduce box size so that they fit into the object?

Comment: cv2.minAreaRect returns center, size and angle: w = w - 1; h = h - 1